# MsBuild not generating PDB files in Release configuration

Tags: msbuild

```
<MSBuild Projects="$(ProjectFile)"  Targets="_WPPCopyWebApplication;"
Properties="OutDir=..\publish;Configuration=Release;Platform=AnyCPU" />
```

I am using above script to publish Asp.Net project. In the project settings, I have absolutely made sure debug symbols are generated in release mode. Still MsBuild is not generating the pdb files in the output.

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>Full</DebugType>
    <DefineDebug>false</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DocumentationFile>WebProject.xml</DocumentationFile>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: How did you ensured that debug symbols are generated? Which settings did you set for this?

Comment: @Syam Hello, i'm having the same problem. 2 things: i'm only experiencing this since i switched to vs2012, is this the case for you too? What's more, i noticed that .pdbs *are* generated* but then they get deleted right at the build's end. Do this happen for you too?

Comment: @TimVK I have update the question with relevant information from vbproj file

Comment: @bottlenecked yes, I have recently switched to VS 2012. But I don't have this issue building the code in debug configuration.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After looking at the Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets source, I have found a variable (ExcludeGeneratedDebugSymbol) being set to True in Release mode. From the comments, it looks like they wanted to exclude symbols from WebSite project, but the condition is not properly set for WebApplication project.

So, I have decided to override my build scrip from the caller arguments and it worked like a charm. I have not yet ascertained any side affects it may cause or using the undocumented property for future stability, but it works for now.

**From the Microsoft.Web.Publishing.target file**

```
<!--For website we will always exclude debug symbols from publishing unless it is set explicitly by user in website publish profile-->
    <ExcludeGeneratedDebugSymbol Condition="'$(ExcludeGeneratedDebugSymbol)'=='' And '$(_WebProjectType)' == 'WebSite'">True</ExcludeGeneratedDebugSymbol>

    <ExcludeGeneratedDebugSymbol Condition="'$(ExcludeGeneratedDebugSymbol)'=='' And '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">True</ExcludeGeneratedDebugSymbol>
    <ExcludeGeneratedDebugSymbol Condition="'$(ExcludeGeneratedDebugSymbol)'==''">False</ExcludeGeneratedDebugSymbol>
```

**I have updated my script as follows.**

```
<MSBuild Projects="$(ProjectFile)"  Targets="_WPPCopyWebApplication;"
Properties="OutDir=..\publish;Configuration=Release;Platform=AnyCPU"; ExcludeGeneratedDebugSymbol=false />
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also updated your publish profile (.pubxml) file to include that property value. I had to do this today with the new build bits in TFS Build 2015 to have the web publishing include the .pdb files. See example contents of file with property added to bottom.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
This file is used by the publish/package process of your Web project. You can customize the behavior of this process
by editing this MSBuild file. In order to learn more about this please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <publishUrl>C:\Publish</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>False</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeGeneratedDebugSymbol>false</ExcludeGeneratedDebugSymbol>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put this directly in your `*.csproj` file, as the last property group section (right before the `Import` elements):

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <ExcludeGeneratedDebugSymbol Condition="$(DebugSymbols) == true">false</ExcludeGeneratedDebugSymbol>
</PropertyGroup>
```