# MSBuild does not build the PDB files

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I have a solution converted from VS2010 to VS2012. In the Release build, I want it to produce PDB files and full debug symbols because I need to run remote debugging in a production environment.

So I set `Debug Info` to `full` for Release configuration. I also confirmed the followings are in the project manifest file:

```
<DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
<DebugType>full</DebugType>
<Optimized>true</Optimized>
```

But when I run MSBuild, the package it creates doesn't include the PDB files. However, if I use Visual Studio's Publish feature with Release configuration, I end up with PDB files on the target web server. What could be wrong with the Build command?

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe "C:\MyWebApp.csproj"  
  /t:rebuild;package 
  /p:OutPath="C:\MyWebApp\obj" 
  /p:OutputPath="C:\MyWebApp\bin" 
  /p:Configuration=Release 
  /p:Platform=AnyCPU
```

I tried turning off the `Optimized` bit, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 18):

Try adding

> /p:DebugSymbols=true
>
> /p:DebugType=full

If you are publishing a web application then you should also add:

> /p:ExcludeGeneratedDebugSymbol=false

Comment: Worked for me just by adding `/p:DebugSymbols=true`

Answer (score 3):

You can access this straight from the command line:

`msbuild.exe "C:\\MyWebApp.csproj"
   /t:rebuild;package
   /p:OutPath="C:\\MyWebApp\\obj"
   /p:OutputPath="C:\\MyWebApp\\bin"
   /p:Configuration=Release
   /p:Platform=AnyCPU
   /p:DebugType=pdbonly`

Comment: I tried that but still didn't produce the PDB files. and I don't even have `ExcludeGeneratedDebugSymbol` in the project manifest mentioned here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15562311/msbuild-not-generating-pdb-files-in-release-configuration

Comment: Have you tried it without the extra properties... (OutPath, OutputPath, ...)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that, when quoting property values, you have to escape backslashes. C:\Foo.csproj when quoted becomes "C:\\Foo.csproj"

Comment: I tried without the extra properties but no PDB still.

Comment: The backslashes are working for me, my actualy output path is a network share and I get the final zip file there.